Hand strap for both shooting orientations (with battery grip)
I have used a hand strap (SpiderPro brand) for a long time for shooting in a horizontal orientation. I recently got a battery grip for my R6 mk ii since I will be doing a lot of vertical shooting. I really miss the hand strap when I'm in vertical orientation, and it doesn't seem like you can use two SpiderPros simultaneously (one in each orientation). I can't seem to find any straps designed to be "dual" straps so you can insert your hand in either orientation. That seems odd to me - does no one do this? Or can you recommend some gear that will work?

As you have battery grip, use it to hold the camera. Just forget about the strap. Grip also will increase the speed of reaction when you see something unexpected.

With a big lens there's no comparison when holding it for hours for say a sports game with vs without a strap.

For sport games I will use monopod to "hold" the camera and lens. And will prefer landscape orientation... (with eventual crop to portrait)

The best technique is to hold and support the weight of the camera and lens with the left hand (or a monopod/tripod in the case of heavy lens/camera combinations) and use the right hand to operate the controls with a light touch without providing much camera support. This has the benefit of more stable shutter actuations. When the right hand is supporting an appreciable amount of the camera's weight, activating the shutter tends to cause more camera movement than when the left hand is supporting the weight of the camera/lens.

To put it another way, cameras with integrated vertical grips have historically tended to be used by professionals who were taught when they first started out to support the weight of the camera/lens with the left hand and operate the controls with the right. Before IS/IBIS and insanely high usable ISO with recent digital cameras, film often meant much slower exposure times than are now possible for many shooting scenarios and camera stability was a much bigger concern than it now is. Simply put, there was never much, if any, market demand from pros for wrist straps for dual control bodies.

There are simply no mounting points suitable for a hand strap on the bottom.
You could get a long arca swiss plate with a strap loop at one end, like the ProMedia Gear PX6. Attach the top of the SpiderPro to the strap loop, and flip the "tail" back under the plate to secure it in the normal way... like this.

But the whole thing would be secured with only a single 1/4-20 screw and will likely be prone to twisting.

Edit: Apparently some grips do have a strap mount incorporated into them. In that case you only need to add a long plate to secure the tail... that would be better as it would be less prone to twisting.
You could add the bottom hand strap as a second, but that is a lot of material between the plate and vertical grip.

Almost all cameras with vertical grips (or battery grips that attach to the bottom of camera bodies), including the Canon BGR-10 for the R  Mark II have a single strap lug near the right end of the grip in addition to the 1/4-20 receiver closer to the middle. What would be the point of putting a strap on the bottom of a camera without a vertical grip, as your illustration seems to do?

@MichaelC, that's interesting about the Canon grip. I have never seen a gripped Nikon with a strap mount in the grip... I currently use a Z9 and a gripped D850 and neither has it. I've even had third party grips for Nikon that didn't have it. Anyway, I just didn't draw the grip separately; only made the shape more square. I'll edit the answer to include this new-to-me information.

You can cobble together a workable solution "Lego"-style if you adopt a clamp system (such as an Arca Swiss–style).

Start with an L-bracket made for your camera, such as the Really Right Stuff Canon R5 & R6/II plate (w/ grip). This gives you a threaded tripod mounting hole on the "bottom" of your camera, regardless of which grip position you are holding the camera. This also gives you an Arca Swiss mounting plate for each orientation as well.

Use a strap that includes, or can accomodate, some form of quick disconnect system at both ends. For instance, the OP Tech USA E-Z Grip Strap has a pretty bog-standard "squeeze" style strap disconnect at the top end of the strap, that mates with a strap buckle that you leave attached to the camera's top-right strap mounting boss. Buy another set of Uni-Loop connectors so you can mount another strap buckle to the built-in camera strap boss in the battery grip.

Change the strap depending on which orientation you are using the camera.

Alternately, buy a 2nd strap and leave both of them mounted, so you can comfortably and quickly change orientations as needed, as well as remove one of them quickly if needed to mount on a tripod, etc.



yea that sounds like the only thing that could be done. The only concern is that it seems like in the vertical orientation you'd be grabbing the L bracket though, which seems less-than-comfortable. For now I've just been using a simple wrist strap, which gives me at least some insurance if I drop the whole thing without wrist straps :)

I have not yet seen any product that offers a dual hand strap for cameras with battery grip.
For some time I used a spider light strap and a peak design clutch  strap for horizontal orientation, however, the strap has interfered with vertical shooting. I finally stopped using it for this reason.
If this is a bit about camera safety, a possible solution would be using a wrist strap, as that would not interfere that much. However, it would not support holding the camera as a hand strap would. It would just be a limited measure to prevent damage in case of dropping the camera.
I would prefer a neck strap attached to the bottom plate and the left default strap attachment point of the camera, as it does not interfere too much with gripping and is much safer than a wrist strap. On the other hand, it is restricting holding the camera on a stretched arm if that is a use-case for you (taking photos above crowds etc).

Thanks - I got a wrist strap (Peak Design) that makes me feel much better for the time being until/if I figure out a dual-hand-strap solution that makes sense :).
